# How can I specify arbitrary headline numbering in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, header-line

Suppose I have the following org file (`example.org`):

```
* Alpha
** Aleph
* Beta
* Gamma
```

When I export it to HTML I get:

```
1. Alpha
1.1. Aleph
2. Beta
3. Gamma
```

Which is quite useful in most cases. Now suppose I want to have the following HTML output:

```
2.3.1. Alpha
2.3.1.4. Aleph
4.2. Beta
5. Gamma
```

How should I amend `example.org`?

Note that the expected new numbering can't be predicted, it has hence to be specified manually.

Comment: This look pretty arbitrary to me: can you describe an algorithm that would produce this numbering from your input? The standard numbering is of course algorithmically definable (see the code). I'm not sure that yours is.

Comment: I don't think there's a possible algorithm, I would like to specify the numbering manually. The use case is that I need to produce a document that is a selection of headlines (and their content) from another document. So the extract has to reproduce the numbering of the original.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: You should add the use case to the question (i.e. not in a comment): it's an integral part of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, `example.org` has to be written like this:

```
#+OPTIONS:    num:nil
* 2.3.1. Alpha
** 2.3.1.4. Aleph
* 4.2. Beta
* 5. Gamma
```

Comment: The trouble with this is that there is no way to generate it from the original file: you need to generate the exported file and then manually copy the section numbers into `example.org`.  Not my idea of fun but, if it works for you, I will not complain (too much).

Comment: Also you can bypass export using `M-x org-num-mode` from the source file and typing down the numbers instead of copy-pasting them.